# ggplot to add space in between group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on this hazard ratio chart, using ggplot function and hope you guys could help. I am trying to add the space in between the group “Income” and “Region” . There is function called position_dodge, but I still not quite get it yet. See the image below for the layout. I'm trying to get something liekt that.  Thanks in advance for help~! here is my current code, and the position_dodge not helping with adding space right now

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using facets with free scales to achieve this?

Comment: I agree with Teun that facets are likely to easiest way to do this (I've done it that way in the past). We can't show you how without a reproducible example.

Comment: *"here is my current code"* ... did you forget to add it?